# Query string redirection with htaccess with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

On a website I'm working on now I need to set up a redirection that eliminates query strings, but need to make exceptions for certain parameters like "ver", "dir", "load", etc.

for example

- `www.myweb.com/?ver=3.5&load=min&dir=ltr` this would be OK.
- `www.myweb.com/?id=123` this would redirect to www.myweb.com.

I have the following code that redirects every query string except on js and css

```
    RewriteEngine on

    # redirect to same URI, but without query string
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301]

    # except .js and .css
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(?!js|css)([^.]*)$ $1\.php [L]
```

That eliminates all query string, how can I add the parameters exceptions?

Thanks

Comment: Will the query string be exact that, only changing the values? or will it contain parts of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to remove all query string parameters except for any variation of ver/load/dir through only htaccess and regular expressions.

If you have something like:

> www.myweb.com/?q=q&a=a&**ver=3.5**&z=z&w=w&**load=min**&x=x&**dir=ltr**&c=c&d=d

It's going to be hard to extract out only any number of ver/load/dir params:

> www.myweb.com/?ver=3.5&load=min&dir=ltr

You're better off doing something like this:

```
# remove all params if no ver/dir/load
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(ver|dir|load)=[^&]+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]

# query string isn't only ver/dir/load params, cleanse them with a php script:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(&?(ver|dir|load)=[^&]+)+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !qs-clean\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /qs-clean.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in the `qs-clean.php` script, you'd have something like:

```
<?php

$qs="";

if(isset($_GET['load']))
   $qs=$qs . '&load=' . $_GET['load'];

if(isset($_GET['ver']))
   $qs=$qs . '&ver=' . $_GET['ver'];

if(isset($_GET['dir']))
   $qs=$qs . '&dir=' . $_GET['dir'];



header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved");
header('Location: /' . $_GET['page'] . '?' . substr($qs,1));

?>
```

So it would do the redirect and print out only the parameters you care about.

---

If it's a matter of just not removing the query string if either the ver/dir/load parameters *ever* appear in the query string, that can be done with mod_rewrite. It's the redirect that was being done in the other case:

```
# remove all params if no ver/dir/load
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(ver|dir|load)=[^&]+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```